# Is it possible to get a "bad" OS install if using iLO virtual media to install the OS? How do I tell?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, installation, hp-proliant, ilo

I am installing Windows 2012 R2 via Virtual CD ROM against an HP Proliant via iLO.

On my first attempt at installing the OS, I got an error saying the EULA was missing and the installation was corrupt.  I have used this ISO many times, and know it's OK (from licensing.microsoft.com).  I re-attempted the installation, and everything worked fine.

But since many files might become corrupt, besides the EULA, I think it's possible for some aspect of an iLO based OS install to fail with equal probability of what happened above.

- Does installing the OS via iLO have a chance of being corrupt without knowing it within the installer?
- Is there any OS protection, or other verification I can use to verify the core installation?

Answer (score 1):

Not usually, but if you're concerned, it's probably a networking issue. Think about what's between you and the ILO... I've had installs fail occasionally via ILO, but if your reattempt worked, don't worry to much about it.

Comment: For me, it's usually an ocean.